# pointer variable defined by typedef

Tags: c++, pointers

I know that the code below works.

```cpp
        int* pn;
        pn = new int;
```

So I tried to apply it in same way, in my custom class.

```cpp
class Matrix {
private:
    typedef struct ex_node* ex_pointer;
    typedef struct ex_node {
        int ex_data;
        ex_pointer next;
    };
    
public:
    void examplefunction() {
        ex_pointer node;
        node = new ex_node;     //error here
    }
};
```

The error says that I cannot assign "ex_node*" type value to "ex_pointer"type entity.

But ex_pointer is defined as ex_node*.

Is ex_pointer different type from ex_node*?
How can I remove this error?

Comment: Stop using `typedef` like `C` in `C++`. There was no need to use it in the definition of `ex_node`

Comment: Declaring a `typedef` for a pointer, IMHO, is overkill.  Much more meaningful to use the pointer declaration format.

Comment: Thank you for comments! I'll try to use typedef in c++ way and stop using pointer by typedef

Comment: You can change the code to `node = ex_pointer(new ex_node);` to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the question and Jason Liam already provided different ways to fix your code. But I'd like to answer your first questions, which are entirely valid: **"The error says that I cannot assign "ex_node*" type value to "ex_pointer"type entity. But ex_pointer is defined as ex_node*. Is ex_pointer different type from ex_node*?"*

Let's check exactly what the compiler says:

```
error: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'Matrix::ex_pointer' (aka 'ex_node *') 
       from 'Matrix::ex_node *'

        node = new ex_node;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, the problem is that node is of type `Matrix::ex_pointer`, that is a `ex_node *`.  `new ex_node` instead is of type `Matrix::ex_node *`. The former is a pointer to a `struct ex_node` defined in the global namespace, while the latter is a pointer to a `struct ex_node` defined within `class Matrix`.

Apparently forward declaring a struct *within a typedef* assumes that the struct is in the global namespace, which in your case is not correct. You can fix it (as suggested also by Jason Liam) by forward declaring your struct before the typedef:

```
class Matrix {
    struct ex_node;
    typedef struct ex_node* ex_pointer;

    struct ex_node {
        int ex_data;
        ex_pointer next;
    };

public:
    void examplefunction() {
        ex_pointer node;
        node = new ex_node;
    }    
};
```

Finally: don't hide that pointer behind a typedef.

Comment: Ohhhh I finally got what was the problem. I had no idea that typedef assumes that sturuct is global. Thanks!

Comment: If this answers your question, remember to mark it as accepted when you'll have enough reputation.

Comment: @Juyeon "*I had no idea that typedef assumes that struct is global*" - the typedef itself doesn't assume anything. You are **forward declaring** a struct from *inside* the typedef, it is the forward declaration that is putting the struct in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

A more C++ way(and correct way) of doing this would be remove the unnecessary `typedef`s as shown below:

```
class Matrix {
private:
    
    
    
    struct ex_node {
        int ex_data;
//------vvvvvvvv---------->directly using ex_node* is more clear IMO
        ex_node* next;
    };
    using ex_pointer = ex_node*; 
    
    

public:
    void examplefunction(){
    //------vvvvvvvvvv---------->you can use ex_pointer if you really want
            ex_pointer node;
            node = new ex_node;;     //works now 
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bnYsMq19K)

---

##### Method 2

If you want you can still use alias as shown below. Here we provide a **forward declaration** for `ex_node` inside the `Matrix` so that we can use typedef/using with it.

```
class Matrix {
private:
    
    struct ex_node; //forward declaration
    using ex_pointer = ex_node*; 
    
    struct ex_node {
        int ex_data;
//------vvvvvvvvv---------->use ex_pointer 
        ex_pointer next;
    };
    
    
    

public:
    void examplefunction(){
   
            ex_pointer node;
            node = new ex_node;;    
    }
};
```

Comment: I chose to not use `ex_pointer`  but use `ex_node*`! And I never thought that i can use `using`. Thanks!!

Comment: @Juyeon You're welcome :) Also you made the right decision in not using `ex_pointer`. And yes, `using` is also a feature that c++ provides. I prefer it(`using`) over `typedef` but that is mostly personal preference.

Comment: @JasonLiam: Maybe a little more then personal prefence actually: The IsoC++ does share your recommendation: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rt-using

Comment: @nick Good to know, now I can use this guideline as a reference. Also your last comment may help future readers so I will recommend keeping it here as sometimes user delete their comment after some time.